# Why won't my c# program run?

Tags: c#

I'm a uni student just starting to learn c#. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I have searched and I don't think know enough yet.
this is my program, note that I have not finished a few functions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            public void welcome()
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Fuel Consumption Calculator "+"r/n"+"Are you using Metric 1 or Imperial 2 ?");
            }


            public void check()
            {
                string choice;
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice == "1")
                {
                    calcmetric();
                }
                else
                {
                    calcimperial();
                }

            }
             public void calcmetric()
             {
             }
            public void calcimperial()
             {
             }
        }

    }
}
```

In Visual Studio I have two errors: one saying a '}' is expected after `Main`; and there is an error at the very end saying "type or namespace definition error".

Comment: You can´t declare method within method (i.e. `check` within `Main`)

Comment: there is nothing to run in your program firstly, second you have to resolve the errors you have ,

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring methods inside a method. This is wrong.

Change it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //call other methods here
        welcome();
        check();
        //....            
    }
    public static void welcome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fuel Consumption Calculator "+"r/n"+"Are you using Metric 1 or Imperial 2 ?");
    }


    public static void check()
    {
        string choice;
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice == "1")
        {
            calcmetric();
        }
        else
        {
           calcimperial();
        }

    }
    public static void calcmetric()
    {
    }
    public static void calcimperial()
    {
    }
}
```